# How to show all values in amstock chart?

Tags: amcharts

I have an AmStockChart graph that groups values:

[image]

I have a value with dates like

- 2014-01-01 00:05,
- 2014-01-01 00:10,
- 2014-01-01 00:15,
- ......
- 2014-01-02 00:00 and so on.

However, AmStockChart is grouping those values and only showing them when I zoom in. Is there a way to show all the values without having to zoom in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should set maxSeries property of CategoryAxesSettings to 0.